# how can i create a chart to analyze my Tasks list for HelpDesk?

Tags: 2007, reports, chart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i create a chart based on a TaskList?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10414/how-can-i-create-a-chart-based-on-a-tasklist)

All i need is a chart that can calculate the values from a List, and tell me something like technician Vadim Babaev (Column "Assigned To") had 10 tasks, 5 of them completed, 5 are in progress.(Column "Job Status"). I have two more columns, Title - the title of the problem, and % Complete column that shows completeness of the job in percents.

p.s. Please give me some ideas how to manage it. I couldn't realize it with calculated columns, couldn't do it with PKI or Indicators, I think that it should be done in Dashboard designer i guess... but can't do it during the whole week. I'd be very grateful for any help.
Really need it.
i'm using Sharepoint Server 2010, but if you know how to do it in 2007 please don't pass by:(
right at least where to dig...

Answer (score 0):

I provided some options on another question.

[How can i create a chart based on a TaskList?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10414/how-can-i-create-a-chart-based-on-a-tasklist/14625#14625)

Those will allow you options on graphing it, but you will configure your grouping when you deploy your charts.