# How can i create a chart based on a TaskList?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, reports, chart

The problem is harder than it sounds. will try to describe it.

I have a HelpDesk Task list that consist of a such columns.

```
...... Title ..... | ... Assigned to |     Progress    |     Due Date    |  etc.

Printer problem    |      .Vadim.    |       50% .     |     15.03.10    |
```

Now i need to create some chart  that will take information from this task list, and give me such an info like: Technician Vadim has 10 tasks, 3 of them completed  50%, 7 comlited 100%.

Is it possible to do it? I've tried it with PKI, Indicators, without success.

Please i really need it. If you can show me the way or even direction where to dig, i can do it. Just tell me where and with whith tools i have to  do it.

I'm using Sharepoint enterprise server 2010, i've dashboard and share-point designer installed.

Thank you very much!

Comment: this is the list:
 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23076913/helpdesk.bmp

Comment: This product may do what you want - Pivot Tables and Charts without excel services - http://www.pentalogic.net/sharepoint-products/pivotpoint/dashboard-example-uses/workload-monitoring-dashboard

Comment: I didn't want to create potential dublicate but there might newer solution options for such tasks. I am looking to figure out the way using embedded JS using plotting tools like "D3.js". Add the moment I am stuck at 2 points. 1) to fetch the data existing task list (I believe I can figure this), 2) the way it updates plots seems strange (I need click the apply button, otherwise no chart appearing on the page). Is there a basic example showing how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of charting packages available, as well as the .NET chart controls that you could utilize.

A pay for product with support
http://www.dundas.com/dashboard/features/sharepoint-dashboards.aspx

Free alternatives:
http://chartpart.codeplex.com/
http://charts4sharepoint.codeplex.com/

And if you don't have access or cant get a solution installed you can fall back on utilizing JavaScript / XML / XSLT.  Some links to get you started:

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/finally-dynamic-charting-in-wss-no-code-required.aspx

*they use Google charts in above example, but it can be modified and use Yahoo charts, JQuery charts, Fusion Charts, VisiFire charts, or other opensource/free charting tool.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can easily achieve this OOB, following the diff options (only 4 is dependent on 3)

1. Use the OOB Chart WebParts
2. Can use Excel Services, access the data using the data connection/webservice
3. Advanced Sol. : User PowerPivot and design a cube with slicers and dicers :)
4. Advanced Sol. : Use the Power Pivot xls and Datasource into Performance Point and design amazing reports (I think this is an overkill, have to configure cache, security...etc)

Answer (score 1):

You can create/customize SharePoint Gantt chart using SharePoint designer - http://www.indrasani.com/creating-gantt-chart-using-sharepoint-designer/

Answer (score 0):

You can create/customize SharePoint Gantt chart using SharePoint designer - http://www.indrasani.com/?p=16